# Is it safe to handle session with Struts2 Tags

Tags: jsp, struts2, ognl

Im using some Struts2 tags and `OGNL` to validate what would be displayed into a `<div>` tag

```
<s:if test="%{#session.User.getProfile()=='Admin'}">
    //SHOW SOMETHING RELATED WITH ADMINS
</s:if>
<s:else>
       //SOMETHING RELATED WITH NORMAL USERS                
</s:else>
```

This is too simple and i don't know if its safe or maybe i should use a better technique in order to achieve what i'm trying to do

Comment: create seperate pages to admin and other users...

Comment: Not all things should be hard, you know. :) What do you mean by safe?

Comment: @AleksandrM Ahah true, kiss paradigm FTW :)

Comment: Unless you do something pretty wrong, the user cannot modify their own session. You could also use something like Spring Security, which has a wide variety of ways this could be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

The session map that you used in the context is protected by the framework if it's accessed from the client side. On the server side it's used in an ordinary way by OGNL. So, you don't have to worry about it, but to be safe from other possible vulnerabilities you'd better use any of the security framework or servlet security. Struts2 provides `PrincipalAware` actions a security stuff that you can use instead of treating model object as a security.